# Mann Whitney critical value in R is different from the table values

Tags: r, statistics

I'm using `qwilcox(0.05, 5, 7)` to find critical value in R and it gives me the result 7, while in the table with confidence level 0.05 I have the result of 5. Why there is a difference? What command should I use to get critical value of Mann Whitney test?

[image]

Comment: See this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32445/wilcoxon-mann-whitney-critical-values-in-r. The first answer here is a pretty good view of why this happens.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong test. `?qwilcox` as described in the help page `qwilcox gives the quantile function` and not critical values. that could be the result of the disagreement with the table values. 
Check this
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139317/critical-value-for-wilcoxon-one-sample-signed-rank-test-in-r

Comment: Weird. Is there a function that gives critical values for the test? Or I should always subtract 1 from `qwilcox`?